# Conceptual doubt about the use of normal distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let's say we have a set of scores from an exam that can range from 0-10. Given N=30 scores we can compute the mean ($\bar{x}=4.8$) and the standard deviation ($\sigma_{x}=2.0$).  If we use the normal distribution on this data we can get a non zero probabilty of obtaining values smaller than 0 or bigger than 10. I know that the normal distribution is just a way to approximate the real distribution and that this non-sensical values would be a lot smaller given a much larger sample size. But how do I interpret them? If I want to know the probability of getting a score lower than 1 should I integrate from $-\infty$  to 1 or from 0 to 1?

Comment: It is your model, so you can do what you want. Apart from the issue you raise, there is also the question of whether all scores are integers

Answer (score 2):

If you exclude the tail of the distribution without making any adjustment, then if you calculate the entire probability of the range of values you'll get a value less than 1. This is likely to be a problem in many circumstances.

If you really want to avoid having any probability outside of the range of valid scores, then you need to use a distribution which accommodates that. One such option is the [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) which essentially does what you're talking about - cutting off values outside of a given interval - but it adjusts the probabilities appropriately. If there are particular properties of the normal distribution you want to make use of, then you'll have to be careful to ensure that they have an appropriate equivalent.